# Can't catch exception from main in: after() throwing(Exception e) - AspectJ

Tags: java, exception, aop, aspectj, aspect

I am trying to catch an exception that is thrown within my main in my Java class.

My main's code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new something();
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

---

In my aspect, I have created both `after() returning: execution(* main(*)) { advice}` and  `after() throwing(Exception e): execution(* main(*)) { advice }` to find out if an exception is thrown in the main or not, in order to do something different at each advice.

*Note* that inside the second one, I am printing in the output the `e` exception using:

```
System.out.println("Threw an exception: " + e + "Joinpoint: " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toString());
```

---

The problem is that even if I throw an exception in main, and I can see from the output that the pointcut that is matched is the second one (Ouput: `Threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeExceptionJoinpoint: void main(String[])`
), I still get this error in my output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at main(C.java:24)
```

So, as I can understand, I haven't catched the exception, I just identified that an exception happened in main.

Is there a way that I could catch this exception without having to use `around()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't suppress an exception with an `after() throwing` advice, you'll need to use an `around()` advice as you suspected.

```
void around(): execution(* MainClass.main(*)) {
    try {
        proceed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //suppress
        System.out.println("Suppressed an exception: " 
            + e + "Joinpoint: " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toString());
    }
}
```

An `after() throwing` advice is good to run additional code when an exception is thrown at some point of interest of yours but it won't stop the exception from propagating **unless you throw another exception** from your advice code (wrap the suppressed exception if you do so):

```
after() throwing(Exception e): execution(* MainClass.main(*)) {
    System.out.println("Threw an exception: " + e + "Joinpoint: " 
        + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toString());
    throw new RuntimeException("Another exception", e);
}
```

**EDIT**: I'm adding an example on how to emulate `before()`, `after() returning`, `after() throwing` and `after()` advices in an `around() advice` following up a question in a comment on my answer.

```
void around(): execution(* MainClass.main(*)) {
    try {
        //before() code
        System.out.println("Before main started.");

        proceed();

        //after() returning code
        System.out.println("Main exited normally.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //after() throwing code suppressing exception unless you rethrow it
        System.out.println("Suppressed an exception: " + e + "Joinpoint: " 
            + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toString());
    } finally {
        //after() code
        System.out.println("After main executed.");
    }
}
```

This will output the following lines when your main class is run:

```
Before main started.
Main started.
Suppressed an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: errorJoinpoint: void MainClass.main(String[])
After main executed
```

Note that the code for the `after() returning` part doesn't get executed as your main class doesn't finish normally as it throws an exception instead, just as a normal `after() returning` advice would not run in that case.

Comment: When I tried to use `around`, the rest code inside it, didn't work as it should.
It doesn't work either if I have `before()` or `around()`.
Is there a way in around() that I could make my code run as it was in `after`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to emulate `after() returning` in an `around()` advice? Or `after() throwing`? Or both at the same time?

Comment: `after() returning` and `after() throwing` have different advice. When I have these implementations like this, both works correctly BUT i can't catch the exception in main in order not to display this exception in the output as error.
If I try to combine both in one `around()`, and by that I mean put the code of `after() returning` in the `try{` of `around()` and the code of `after() throwing` in the `catch {` of `around()` it doesn't work as it should, even if I don't throw an exception in my main. If I throw an exception in main I can catch that.

Comment: I found out that, the `around()` I have created in order to catch the exception, doesn't work because a second pointcut  which is used in another `around()`, for some reason it is affected when I change `after()` or [`after() returning` and `after() throwing`] to `around()` for the above (`execution(* MainClass.main(*))`).. The pointcut of the `around()` that gets affected,  is a combination of joinpoints that include  `withincode(* main(*)`.

Comment: Well, I can't comment on that as I don't see your whole environment, but I edited my answer to include the `around()` advice example you asked for in your previous comments.

Comment: It worked now as I wanted to.
In summary, I have added an `around()` which has a `try{}` and a `catch{}`.
Within `try{}` the first instruction is `proceed()` so that I can have the code which I had in `after() returning` run properly. The code that I had in `after() throwing`, I placed it in `catch{}`.
Now everything works properly even If I have an exception or not. Thank you!